# parallel execution using selenium and c# in VSTS integrating with MTM

Tags: c#, selenium, mtm

can any please let know how to create and execute the multiple threads on a Coded-UI TestMethod ?

My requirement is ,i must be able to execute the C# code in TestMethod on multiple browsers parallely when we click run in Microsoft Test Manager.We implemented a Keyword driven framework which executes all cases from a single TestMethod.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single instance of a browser based Coded UI test. In order to run multiple tests, you will need to have multiple test agents and then send tests to each agent from the Test Controller.

Comment: Hi ChrisBint ,thanks for your help.I did some R&D and able to figure out the solution now i am able to run the cases parallely on multiple browsers.But i have a problem like TestAgent is not copying the Chrome driver file from Build Location to its(AgentLocation) Location.For now i mentioned it statically while opening the IEbrowser.Is there any size limit on data which Agent copies from Build Location to its Location ? Please help me with this.